# Describing vector equation geometrically

Tags: analytic-geometry, vectors

How would I describe geometrically the vector equation:

$$\vec{x} = s(0,2,1) + t(1,1,-1) ,\qquad s,t \in \Bbb R$$

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you let $\vec{x}=(x,y,z)$, this gives the equations $x=t, y=2s+t, z=s-t$;

so $y-2z=3t$ and therefore $3x-y+2z=0$.

This shows that the given vector equation represents a plane in $\mathbb{R^3}$ passing through the points

$(0,0,0)$, $(0,2,1)$, and $(1,1,-1)$.

---

More generally, the vector equation $\vec{x}=s(a,b,c)+t(d,e,f)$ represents a plane passing through

the points $(0,0,0)$, $(a,b,c)$, and $(d,e,f)$.

Answer (score 0):

this is equation of plane so you can using cross product and obtain normal of plane and 
write ax+by+cz+d=0 that (a,b,c) is normal vector and d obtain by an optional point.

Comment: So would it be correct to say that this vector is a plane in R^2? Also, how would I know if it passes through the origin or not?

Comment: @user176330 No. Vectors are not planes. As it runs through parameters, it describes a plane, though.

Comment: this is plane in R^3.suppose you have one vector and i ask question from you if you suppose all coefficient of this vector for example (-2*vector,10*vector, ...) what shape will obtain?yes line!now we have two vector that they are in different direction so if we suppose all coefficient of those we have plane.(sorry for my bad english)